# How to use http digest authentication from fiddler?

Tags: fiddler, digest-authentication

Tooling around with a json REST api, that uses http digest auth.

How can I do the auth dance in fiddler? (Hoping it has some magic to automate the process?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easy answer seems to be: use cURL

```
curl --anyauth --user <username>:<passwd> https://testingapi.com
```